# XCode and developer tools

Tags: iphone, macos

I want to use the FileMerge utility on my mac, but it isn't installed. I searched in Google and there is written that it will be installed with the developer tools. Where can I find the developer tools?  I downloaded the iPhone SDK 3.2 beta 5 and installed it, but I can't find the download location of developer tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPhone SDK should include all the developer tools.

Have you looked in `/Developer/Applications/Utilities/` ?

The tools are part of the Xcode suit which is part of the iPhone SDK.

Comment: then why don't I have the FileMerge?

Comment: @Infinity: Have you looked in `/Developer/Applications/Utilities/` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found it :D
I searched in /Applications/Utilities... big mistake, sorry...

Answer (score 2):

FileMerge is not a great tool. A much better free alternative is [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/TextWrangler/).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the DVDs that came with your Mac ?  If you do, you should find that the developer tools are on the 2nd DVD.  Pop it in the reader and follow the instructions.