# Install Compass on OS X Yosemite

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, compass

I'm trying to install compass using GEM but i have a lot of error.

My macbook pro is running OS X Yosemite.

Anyone have the same problem ?

Thank you for your time. 
Have a nice day

```
sudo gem install compass
Password:
ERROR:  Error installing compass:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20141019-17085-1dv9dek.rb extconf.rb
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/rbconfig.rb:213: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.5/ext/ffi_c in PATH, mode 040777
checking for ffi.h... /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:549:in `block in try_compile'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:502:in `with_werror'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:549:in `try_compile'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1044:in `block in have_header'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:895:in `block in checking_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in `postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:894:in `checking_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1043:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:16:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-14/2.0.0/ffi-1.9.5/gem_make.out
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [XCode and developer tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538922/xcode-and-developer-tools)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, this seems to be successfully answered at [Installing 'Compass' via the command line receive error "extconf failed, exit code 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584355/installing-compass-via-the-command-line-receive-error-extconf-failed-exit-co)

You evidently need to first install development tools   (xcode-select --install), then install compass

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

well you should not be installing gems globally for one thing. I would highly recommend installng rbenv and then the version of ruby you would like to have, before you install compass and other gems. Then you can install gems at a user level and don't have to worry about setting write permissions on directories outside of the users. - which appears to be the problem in this case.

Just follow the instructions here for rbenv https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv and then install the ruby build plugin https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build

Answer (score 0):

Just run `sudo chmod go-w /usr/local/` from terminal as administrator.

This worked for me