# Using ruby-gems and compass on OS X + macports

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, compass-sass, macports

Want use `compass` & `sass` and some "gems" for the compass.

I know nothing about the `ruby` and his ecosystem, and honestly - i need only the running `compass watch` - nothing more.

Because don't want touch the system-wide installed ruby, want use the `macport`'s one.

*I'm already using the macports for many packages, of course have the all OS X developer packages installed (Xcode + command line tools), therefore this question isn't a duplicate to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26451501/632407).*

Could please someone write how to use the macport's `compass`?

Already did:

```
$ sudo port install ruby
$ port select --list ruby 
Available versions for ruby:
none (active)
ruby18
```

so activated the macports one

```
$ sudo port select --set ruby ruby18
```

ok, now the `type ruby` return `/opt/local/bin/ruby`. So, installed the `rb-rubygems` package

```
sudo port install rb-rubygems
```

but the `type gem` still returns `/usr/bin/gem` **:(**

also installed

```
 $sudo port install rb-compass
```

but the `compass` command is still `/usr/bin/compass` - simply terrible.

So, please - could someone give an advice how to *activate and use* the whole `macports` ruby-suite? Some step-by-step guide would be nice. I simply need:

- compass (+ some gems for the compass)
- sass (needs it the compass)
- ruby
- gem
- and whatever else what is needed for the `compass`.

Ps: i haven't problem with any other macport's packages - only the "ruby+macport logic" is somewhat unclear for me.

Answer (score 0):

MacPorts avoids installing stuff in places that could also be used by the same software using different ruby versions. For this reason, `rb-compass` does not install to `/opt/local/bin/compass` where you would expect it. It does, however, install the `compass` executable in a couple of places you could use directly, add to your path, or symlink from `/opt/local/bin/compass`:

```
$ port contents rb-compass | grep -E 'compass(-1.8)?$'
  /opt/local/bin/compass-1.8
  /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin/compass
  /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass
  /opt/local/libexec/ruby1.8/compass
```